# Nginx working with SSL but Private Key mismatch error

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, private-key

## Used to work

I bought a Rapid SSL from name.com and used the below command to generate the `.csr` and `.key` files:

```
sudo openssl req -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/server.csr
```

I answered all questions which this command asked. I then provided the `.csr` to name.com and successfully generated the server/intermediate certificates. I then followed the steps mentioned at https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO17664 and installed this certificate at my nginx server. I was able to open the HTTPS version of my site as well.

## PrivKey overwritten by mistake

Then, to try something else, I ran the command (sudo openssl req... ) again with different answers this time and generated a **new** `server.key` file. Unfortunately, I didn't save the first `server.key` file.

Post modification of nginx .conf file, when I tried to restart the server, I got the below error:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

Seeing this error, I realized I have overwritten the `server.key` file. I tried to generate the key again with same answers I gave for the first time but still the key mismatch error is coming.

## nginx is still running.

My nginx server is still running and I am able to access the HTTPS version of the site but my life is in trouble without the private key. I have gone through the below links but still stuck:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191463/ssl-error0b080074x509-certificate-routinesx509-check-private-keykey-values
2. [nginx ssl certificate issue key values mismatch](https://serverfault.com/questions/408112/nginx-ssl-certificate-issue-key-values-mismatch)

#### PrivKey modulus != PubKey modulus

I confirmed by running the below commands that my certificate (issued by name.com) and private keys don't match:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server_orig.cert | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5
```

### Any hope?

Is there anything which I can do to find out the private key since Nginx is still up and running? In case not, should I get the certificate re-issued by Geotrust?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## Talk to cert vendor

Depending on your vendor, they may either insist on re-payment, or just do this free of charge.

I would not spend time looking for the cert in nginx's RAM. Sure, if https still works, then the privkey must still be there, and [extraction from](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55471/how-would-you-know-a-certificate-private-key-if-you-extracted-it-from-ram-or-wo) [RAM is possible](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8067454), but if you have never done this before, then just buying another cert is the quicker option.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, it looks much better now. I checked with Geotrust, they have an option of Re-issuing the certificate. If I do that, I should be able to generate a new key & certificate I think. Should I try doing that? Any possible issues there?

Comment: @AAgg: Try to get somebody on the phone. Failing that, try mail.

Answer (score 0):

@AAgg, Just reissue the certificate from your cert provider with new CSR and Key.

I have done that several times without having any issues.

Comment: Why this downvote? Is this not a practical solution?